# How to delete (Not Void) an Envelope from DocuSign using API. Also does DocuSign charges for deleted Envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to delete an envelope which was created by mistake. I know we can void it but DocuSign still charges for it. [Referring to this](https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000069kAaL/is-a-void-envelope-charged-for) I no longer need the envelope. Is there a way we can permanently delete it using DocuSign APIs?

Does DocuSign charge for deleted envelopes as well? Any more information on Envelope Costing would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can `purge` the envelope.

[Using the DocuSign web app](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-envelope-purge)

### Using the API

Update the envelope object: set `purgeState` to `documents_queued`

See the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/update/)

But my guess is that your account was charged when the envelope was sent. For more info on DocuSign's charges/costs, talk with your DocuSign salesperson.